# Intercepting HTTP Response headers with Angular 4.3's HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, http-headers

This is how I send my **HTTP request:**

```
return this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response' })
```

I would like to **read the HTTP headers of a HttpResponse** in my HttpInterceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request)
            .do(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.logger.logDebug(event); // Headers are missing here
                }
            })
            .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The interceptor is **provided like this** in my app.module.ts:

{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
  multi: true
}

**The event seems to have no headers**, and even in the Chrome Dev Console I cannot see any headers:

[image]

**However, when using Postman, I can see the headers** in the response (as expected)

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →14766
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Fri, 04 Aug 2017 14:50:46 GMT
Server →WildFly/10
X-Powered-By →Undertow/1
```

**How can I reveal these headers in Angular ?**

The official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) for HTTP says to get the headers like this:

```
http
  .get<MyJsonData>('/data.json', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<MyJsonData>.
    // You can inspect its headers:
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Custom-Header'));
    // And access the body directly, which is typed as MyJsonData as requested.
    console.log(resp.body.someField);
  });
```

Comment: How do you register this interceptor?

Comment: I edited my post, adding this information

Comment: What is logged in Angular's response?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the response

Comment: take a look in the `HttpHeaders` doc. There are a `get()` and a `getAll()` methods. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

Comment: Well yes I know, but they are empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. It was (of course) a CORS Problem. I am using a [CORS Filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html) and I needed to explicitely expose my custom header. I hope this can help others eventually.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it drives one crazy the CORS business. For anyone interested on Spring Boot, you have to add your header name to exposedHeaders method on CorsRegistry.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a server-side CORS filter configuration.

> By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to
>   list them using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Use **`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`** to expose the headers.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 3):

To see the headers, access the 'headers' within the response. The headers are lazily evaluated it seems, thus they are not visible. I suppose that the headers get evaluated only when you explicitly ask for them using `resp.headers.get`. However, you can get the list of headers in the response using `res.headers.keys()`. Eg.

```
yourFunction.subscribe((res:HttpResponse<any>)=>{console.log('response from server:',res);
      console.log('response headers',res.headers.keys())
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not related to Angular. The problem is CORS limits headers by default and you do not see "*X-Custom-Header*" header when call CORS requests. So, adjust server to let it send X-Custom-Header.

There are **TWO** different headers that need to be added:

1. **`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`**
2. **`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`**

**`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`** must be provided in response of OPTIONS request (pre-flight).

**`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`** must be provided in response to the actual (POST/GET) request.

> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom-Header